# Crytical Point and null Differential

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R};$

U open, bounded; f differentiable in U;

$\forall b \in \partial U, x \rightarrow b \Rightarrow f(x) \rightarrow 0$

Then there is $x_0 \in U ; f'(x_0) = 0$.

What I've tried: for $m = 1$, this is Rolle's theorem. $f(b_1) = f(b_2) = 0$, then $f'$ assumes negative and positive values, then by mean value theorem, it must assume 0 value.

For $m = 2, (x, y) \in U$, consider the vertical lines $x = x_0, b_1(x) \le y  \le b_2(x)$.

For each $x$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ assume negative and positive values (or else f would be constant in y), then it must assume 0 value.

$\alpha = \{(x,y) ; \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y) = 0\}$ is a curve.

Now let's consider $f |_\alpha$. How to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} | _\alpha$ assumes negative and positive values? Therefore $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (p) = 0, \exists p \in \alpha$.

For $m \ge 3, (x^1, ..., x^{m - 1}, y) \in U, $ consider the lines $x = x_0 = (x_0^1, ..., x_0^{m-1})$

$b_1(x) \le y \le b_2(x)$

For each $x$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ assume negative and positive values (or else f would be constant in y), then it must assume 0 value.

How to show that: $M = \{(x,y) ; \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y) = 0\}$ is a hyperface ; $\dim M  = m - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

For the dimension $2$ case, you want to show that $\partial f / \partial x$ vanishes somewhere on $\alpha = \{(x,y)\in U: \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = 0\}$. Now, $\alpha$ is not necessarily a curve, but it does contain one (assuming $f$ is $C^1$). So suppose WLOG that $\alpha$ is a curve that extends from $\partial U$ to $\partial U$ and then apply Rolle's theorem to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ with respect to some parametrization of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sup_U\,f = M > 0.$ Then there exists a sequence $x_k$ in $U$ such that $f(x_k)\to M.$ Because $\overline U$ is compact, there is a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x_o \in \overline U.$ This $x_0\not \in \partial U,$ otherwise $f(x_{n_k}) \to 0,$ contradiction. Thus $x_0 \in U,$ and $f(x_0)=M$ by continuity. Therefore $f$ has a maximum at $x_0,$ which implies $f'(x_0)=0.$
Same argument if $\inf_U\,f < 0.$ If neither of these conditions hold, then $f\equiv 0$ and we can have a beer.

Comment: $\sup f = M$. There is a sequence $(x_0, x_1, ...)$ such that $f(x_k) \rightarrow M$. Does this imply that $x_k \rightarrow p = f^{-1}(M)$?

Comment: No, $f$ can assume the value $M$ at more that one point. A simple case: $U=(0,3\pi),f(x)=\sin x.$ Let $(x_k)$ be the sequence $\pi/2, 5\pi/2, \pi/2, 5\pi/2,\dots.$ Then $f(x_k) = M = 1$ for all $k,$ but $(x_k)$ is not convergent. However, a subsequence will be convergent, as in my proof.

Comment: That's a property of complete ordered field. It fails in $\mathbb{Z}$.